# What could be a translation of classic-style French titles, such as "Du contrat social"?

Tags: french

In order to write classic-style titles in a French text, the technique of using a *préposition* before the remaining words of the title is often used. A widely known example is Rousseau's "Du contrat social". Even tough that style is pretty old-fashionned, modern French texts might content such literary sugar, e.g. some news articles or research papers. A few examples, extracted from that [website](https://www.senscritique.com/posts/Silence_le_christianisme_l_histoire_du_Japon_et_le_cinema_de/10584), could be:

- "De l'incompréhension du propos";
- "De la méconnaissance du Japon".

I was wondering how the style of those titles could be kept in an English translation and how to have an equivalent English aesthetic effect.

Comment: The English equivalent is, for example, [***On** the Origin of Species*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Origin_of_Species)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, requesting translatiion and style advice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you for your answer. It is a shame I forgot that example.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Actually, I browsed the web for an hour to find an answer to my question. That question and FumbleFingers answer may be useful for someone.

Comment: During the late 1970s in the UK a government  approach to policy, supported by various sections of society (I'm not too sure about that bit) was called The Social Contract. This was based on Rousseau's phrase and concept.

Comment: We once had a question here asking for advice on keeping goldfish. An answer would have probably helped more people than an answer to this question will. They're both off-topic questions. 'On ...' is obsolescent/obsolete in English.

Comment: @Lyudline: There's also ***Of** Mice and Men* and ***About** a Boy*. But they're not really good examples, and offhand I can't think of better ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, the preposition *de* in French means “about”. This is a relatively rare meaning of the preposition, which is usually closer to “of”. *De* at the beginning of a title in French comes from [*de* in Latin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/de#Latin). In Latin, *de* in this context means “about” and was often used at the beginning of titles, e.g. [*De rerum natura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_rerum_natura) “On the Nature of Things”, [*De legibus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Legibus) “On the Laws”, [*De contemptu mundi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_of_Cluny) “On Contempt for the World”, … In Latin, and later in French up to the classical period, this form of title was very common for works of philosophy and natural philosophy (i.e. science).

For these Latin titles I've given what seems to be the usual English translation. As you can see, the preposition *on* is traditionally used. *On*  also traditionally commonly starts the title of books about philosophy and science in English: [*On Liberty*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Liberty), [*On the Origin of Species*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Origin_of_Species), …

But *of* is also used, for example [*Of the Interpretation of Nature*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Works_of_Francis_Bacon,_Volume_1/Miscellaneous_Tracts_II), [*Of Liberty and Necessity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Hobbes#Works), … [Rousseau's work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Social_Contract) is classically translated as *The Social Contract* or *Of the Social Contract*.

Starting a title with *de* sounds as old-fashioned in French as starting a title with *on* or *of* does in English.

Answer (score 0):

Starting a title with "On" or "Of" in English isn't old-fashioned at all.  It is, however, an indication that the writer has some familiarity with literature.

Consider William Zinnser's classic book, "On Writing Well". The title was not considered "old-fashioned" when it was published in 1976, nor is its title considered old-fashioned now.

Comment: Do you have a source for it not being considered old-fashioned?